# Doomsday Prediction

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a calculus problem I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be appreciated!

Doomsday prediction. In $1960$, three electrical engineers at the University of Illinois published a paper in Science titled "Doomsday." Based on world population growth data from $1000$ AD to $1960$ AD, the engineers found that population growth was faster than proportional to the population size. Using the data, they modeled the growth of the population as

$dP/dt = 0.4873P^2 \:\:$    $P(0) = 0.2$

where $P$ is the population size in billions and $t$ is centuries after $1000$ AD.

1) Solve this differential equation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm really unsure of how to set this up

Comment: Why are you removing your own questions?

Comment: Indeed, it is considering defacing, even if it is your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have a "nice form" differential equation here, you can use [Separation of Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) and integration to solve.  Note that

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=0.4873P^2$$

can be written as

$$\frac{dP}{P^2}=0.4873dt$$

Now you can integrate both sides

$$\int\frac{dP}{P^2}=\int0.4873dt$$
Thus

$$-\frac{1}{P}+C_P=0.4873t+C_t$$

To finish, note that $C_P$ and $C_t$ are arbitrary constants due to the indefinite integrals.  Thus we can rewrite as

$$-\frac{1}{P}=0.4873t+C$$

which is the same as

$$P=\frac{1}{C-0.4873t}$$

for some real $C$.  Now as $P(0)=0.2, C=5$  So finally we have

$$P=\frac{1}{5-0.4873t}$$

As the denominator approaches $0$, the population approaches $\infty$.  This occurs when $5-0.4873t=0$ Thus $t=10.2606197....$ and as $t$ is the number of centuries after $1000$ AD, we can expect an infinite population in $10$ years from now.

Comment: Ah yes.  Thanks.  Typo indeed.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I really don't understand this one very well. Any tips on reducing? Do i do anything with the Cp or Ct?

Comment: I've updated my answers to deal with the constants and solved for your function $P$

Comment: Doomsday , I guess, is at time t=C/0.4873 . As t approaches this time, the population goes to infinity.